# 'Ask' printer for printing status

Tags: usb, serial-connection

I'm using [Artillery Hornet](https://artillery3d.com/products/artilleryc2ae-hornet-3d-printer-build-volume-220x220x250mm-ultra-quite-printing-32bit-mainboard-dc-heat-plate-nozzle-180e28483-240e28483-04mm) printer running Marlin firmware.

Is there a way to **ask/query** printer status via its USB/Serial interface? Without OctoPrint, etc.

Example (something like this):

```
Arduino: Hey are you done printing?

Printer: Not yet
```

<sub>This idea is inspired by vehicle OBD, where you can query the engine RPM by sending a [PID](https://www.csselectronics.com/pages/obd2-pid-table-on-board-diagnostics-j1979) through CanBus interface. So, I wondered if we could do something similar with a 3D printer.</sub>

Comment: Without OctoPrint implies SD printing, look into `M27`. I've never used it so I don't post an answer.